# What's the grammatical category of the word "todos" in the sentence "Todos los forasteros tenían [...]"?

Tags: gramática

> **Todos** los forasteros que por aquel tiempo recorrían las calles de Macondo tenían que hacer sonar su campanita para que los enfermos supieran que estaba sano.

At first, I thought it was a determiner, but I'm not sure. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, "todos" in "todos los forasteros" is a determiner, because the noun "forasteros" is there.

If the noun is absent, then "todos" is a pronoun.